# set position relative to another element

Tags: jquery, css

Suppose of the following html:

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Now, the `.foo` is relative to the `.header` and I wish I could set `.foo` position in accordance with `.footer`. That is if I use absolute position for `.foo` then it should be relative to `.footer`.

Please note: I cannot append the `.foo` into `.footer` for some reason.

Is it possible?

Comment: short answer with css you can't unfortunately

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can use jquery to find footer's position and apply it to .foo. But i am not sure whether it works